# Any news about a Malazan RPG?

Tags: publishing

Has anyone seen anything about whether a professionally published RPG based on Stephen Erickson's *Malazan Book of the Fallen* is in production or in discussion?

I've done some poking around, but most of the information I see is outdated or relates to people speculating on how they could houserule various systems to get a Malazan feel.

Comment: I don't know of anything, although I wish I did. You probably know this but for the sake of completeness, the books were based on a GURPS campaign.

Comment: Bryant, that's a cool addition. Can you cite a source for that?

Comment: The information about the GURPS Campaign is in Steven Erikson's introduction to Gardens of the Moon Redux edition.  He also mentions something in the foreword to Esslemont's Night of Knives, iirc.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is too localised in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only help with my web search skills.

[Fantasy Fan](http://www.fantasy-fan.org/index.php/News/2009/3/12/Malazan-RPG/) discusses the project, but this is an article from 2009. The [Malazan Project forums](http://www.modcraft.net/community/index.php?showforum=862) is pretty dead, though there is recent activity. I suspect that the organizers of the MMO and RPG project aren't really doing a great job.

[Malazan Empire](http://malazanempire.com) is an active site dedicated to role-playing in Erickson's world. However, discussion of a dedicated Malazan RPG hasn't happened there for years.

[Douglas Walker](http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=23449712) was working on a Malazan RPG. I don't know if he is associated with the Malazan Project, who are (as far as I know) the only people with rights licensed from Erickson. Walker talks about his personal project in a [discussion thread](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=2224881237&topic=9363) on the [Malazan Empire Facebook group](http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=2224881237).

As far as I can tell, there is not a well-established Malazan RPG project anywhere. It seems ripe for the picking. If one were to present a reasonably strong proposal to Erickson, he might hand you a license.

Comment: That's about what I had gathered, but I was hoping someone might be able to dig something up.  Sad day.  I imagine it has to happen eventually though.

Answer (score 2):

Malazan was based off a GURPS campaign (and even earlier AD&D), so you sort of have your Malazan RPG right there. You'd need to derive stats by reading the books, but since the books were inspired by characters statted out in GURPS it should be pretty easy to do.

[Wikipedia link with info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malazan_Book_of_the_Fallen#Authorship)